# How do I set each plotly subplot title during graph creation loop?

Tags: python, plotly, subplot, choropleth

I understand that if I want to set all of the subplot titles then I can do that when I declare the figure.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(
    ###
    subplot_titles=['Plot 1', 'Plot 2', 'Plot 3', 'Plot 4', etc.]
)
```

However, I create each subplot graph within a loop, and I think it would be easiest to set each subplot's title during that process. In my case, I created a groupby object based on date, and then I loop through each group (date) dataframe. Each dataframe is used to create the subplot graph, and I'd like the title to be the date. I understand that I *can* figure this out before the loop and set the subplot_titles as normal, but it seems like it'd be a one-liner within the loop. If it matters, the traces I'm adding are choropleths. I'm not going to include a working dataset since my code works fine- I just want to know what line of code I need to add.

```
#Create groupby object, splitting data frame into separate data frames based on 'State'
death_counts_gbo = death_counts_by_week.groupby('End Week') 

#Prepare subplots for choropleths
rows = 4
cols = 7
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=rows, cols=cols,
    specs = [[{'type': 'choropleth'} for c in np.arange(cols)] for r in np.arange(rows)],
)
    
#Graph each state's data
for i, (date, df) in enumerate(death_counts_gbo):
    fig.add_trace(go.Choropleth(
        locations=df['State Abbr'], # Spatial coordinates
        z = df['COVID-19 Deaths per 100k'].astype(float), # Data to be color-coded
        locationmode = 'USA-states', # set of locations match entries in `locations`
        colorscale = 'Reds',
        zmin = 0,
        zmax = 30,
        colorbar_title = "Deaths per 100k",
        text = date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    ), row=i//7+1, col=i%7+1)
    ### This is where I'd like to set the subplot's title to 'date' ###

# Set title of entire figure
# Set each subplot map for the USA map instead of default world map
# Set each subplot map's lake color to light blue
fig.update_layout(
    title_text = 'COVID-19 Deaths per 100k at week ending',
    **{'geo' + str(i) + '_scope': 'usa' for i in [''] + np.arange(2,len(death_counts_gbo)+1).tolist()},
    **{'geo' + str(i) + '_lakecolor': 'lightblue' for i in [''] + np.arange(2,len(death_counts_gbo)+1).tolist()},
)
    
fig.show()
```

EDIT: For my example, I can set the subplot titles during the figure declaration with the following kwarg:

```
subplot_titles = [date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for date in list(death_counts_gbo.groups.keys())]
```

However, for my own edification and if I have a future case where the determination of the subtitle is more involved, I would still like to know how to set it during the loop / after the figure declaration.

EDIT2: Thanks to @rpanai I have a solution, though it required a change in my `make_subplots` declaration, in addition to a one-liner in the loop. He informed me that subtitles are annotations stored in `fig.layout.annotations` and that, while a list of subtitles may be provided to it, calculating the appropriate `x` and `y` coordinates might be a hassle. I worked around this issue by creating temporary subtitles and forcing `make_subplots` to calculate the `x` and `y` coordinates. I then updated the text in the loop.

The updated `make_subplots` figure declaration (subplot_titles added):

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=rows, cols=cols,
    specs = [[{'type': 'choropleth'} for c in np.arange(cols)] for r in np.arange(rows)],
    subplot_titles = ['temp_subtitle' for date in np.arange(len(death_counts_gbo))]
)
```

One-liner (first line of the for-loop):

```
fig.layout.annotations[i]['text'] = date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: HI wex52, the subplot titles are stored as `fig.layout.annotations` when you declared them within `make_subplots` I think that is possible to replicate it creating an `annotations` list during the for loop but i don't think it's worth to deal with `x` and `y` position for each annotation.

Comment: Thank you, @rpanai. I used the information you gave me, wrote a workaround for the issue you raised, and edited my question to include my solution. In addition to a one-liner I needed to add a temporary list of subtitles to my `make_subplots` call so it would calculate the `x` and `y` positions for me.

Comment: @rpanai is right. 
# Initiate a figure with random names with 2x2 subplot
`figure_pl = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, start_cell="bottom-left", subplot_titles=("randname0","randname1","randname2", "randname3"))`
`# Iteratively change the names`
`new_names = [new_name0,new_name1,new_name2,new_name3]`
`for i, new_name in enumerate(new_names):`
 `figure_pl.layout.annotations[i]["text"] = new_name`

Comment: @Arvind Kumar This worked fantastically with latest plotly ast of early 2021. To handle any possible future API changes, print out `figure_pl.layout` and look for the dictionary entrires that define the entries above.

Answer (score 19):

You mentioned that you'd like to be able to edit the titles (that are annotations) *after* you'be built your figures as well. And if you already have *some* title in place, and would like to change them, you can use `fig.for_each_annotation()` in combination with a dict like this:

```
names = {'Plot 1':'2016', 'Plot 2':'2017', 'Plot 3':'2018', 'Plot 4':'2019'}
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text = names[a.text]))
```

Which will turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

You can also easily combine existing titles with an addition of your choice with:

```
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text = a.text + ': ' + names[a.text]))
```

#### Plot 3

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4"))


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
              row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[300, 400, 500], y=[600, 700, 800]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[4000, 5000, 6000], y=[7000, 8000, 9000]),
              row=2, col=2)

fig.update_layout(height=500, width=700,
                  title_text="Multiple Subplots with Titles")

names = {'Plot 1':'2016', 'Plot 2':'2017', 'Plot 3':'2018', 'Plot 4':'2019'}

# fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text = names[a.text]))

fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text = a.text + ': ' + names[a.text]))
         
fig.show()
```